# Escaping bad XML while parsing

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm attempting to parse URLs from an XML sitemap that isn't mine. Unfortunately, some of the XML is poorly written and contains unescaped/invalid characters, such as ampersands.

This is the code block I'm using to parse through my XML file currently:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

name_space = '{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}'

urls = []
for child in root.iter():
    for block in child.findall('{}url'.format(name_space)):
        for url in block.findall('{}loc'.format(name_space)):
            urls.append('{}\n'.format(url.text))

with open('sample_urls.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.writelines(urls)
```

I'm running into this error when it encounters an unescaped URL: ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token).

How can I escape these issues and still continue parsing the file? I've come across the **escape()** function of the *xml.sax.saxutils* module, but not sure the best way to apply it based on what I currently have.

Comment: I found a workaround to ignore the issues by switching to etree under the lxml toolkit and adding 'parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)' and 'tree = ET.parse('test.xml', parser=parser)'. This seems to drop the part of the URL that is problematic and continue. Not as idea as escaping, but can work in a pinch.

Comment: Can't you pre process the XML and remove all invalid characters? Of course you cannot avoid for example elements not being closed but this should be a start. It would also be nice if you can post some XML snippets with the errors that you are encountering.

Comment: The problem I'm having is figuring out how to pre-process without messing up valid parts of the XML. I only need to escape what is within the url node. Here's an example of an XML sitemap which is broken: https://www.samsclub.com/sitemap_products_1.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, try using [`lxml.html`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html). You should be careful though; it ignores namespaces so you need to be sure you're selecting what you intend to select.

Example...

**sitemap_products_1.xml** (Shortened version of the one you linked to. Notice the second `url` has a bad `loc` value.)

```xml
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
 xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
 <url>
  <loc>https://www.samsclub.com/sams/mirror-convex/prod13760282.ip</loc>
  <image:image>
   <image:title>See All 160 Degree Convex Security Mirror - 24&quot; w x 15&quot; h</image:title>
   <image:loc>https://scene7.samsclub.com/is/image/samsclub/0003308171524_A</image:loc>
  </image:image>
 </url>
 <url>
  <loc>https://www.samsclub.com/sams/at&t-3-handset-cordless-phone/prod21064454.ip</loc>
  <image:image>
   <image:title>AT&amp;T 3 Handset Cordless Phone</image:title>
   <image:loc>https://scene7.samsclub.com/is/image/samsclub/0065053003067_A</image:loc>
  </image:image>
 </url>
 <url>
  <loc>https://www.samsclub.com/sams/premium-free-flow-waterbed-mattress-kit-queen/104864.ip</loc>
  <image:image>
   <image:title>Premium Free Flow Waterbed Mattress Kit- Queen</image:title>
   <image:loc>https://scene7.samsclub.com/is/image/samsclub/0040649555859_A</image:loc>
  </image:image>
 </url>
</urlset>
```

**Python 3.x**

```py
from lxml import html

tree = html.parse("sitemap_products_1.xml")

for elem in tree.findall(".//url/loc"):
    print(elem.text)
```

**Output** (Notice the second url is printed in its entirety.)

```
https://www.samsclub.com/sams/mirror-convex/prod13760282.ip
https://www.samsclub.com/sams/at&t-3-handset-cordless-phone/prod21064454.ip
https://www.samsclub.com/sams/premium-free-flow-waterbed-mattress-kit-queen/104864.ip
```

Comment: Interesting, this should definitely work for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Given the example you have posted I would say that using a regular expression would suffice when it comes to the `&` characters. That is unless you completely want to remove such `<loc/>` elements. The "algorithm" below should help you recover such errors.

1. Since the `&t-` inside `.../at&t-3-handset-cordless...` is clearly
   not a valid ampersand character code you can capture everything
   between the `&` and first `;` inside the `<loc/>`'s value or the
   beginning of a closing tag (`</`, which would be the `</loc>`).
2. Then you can check whether the captured string is indeed an
   ampersand character code (since these are limited you can create a
   set and check if the string is inside). If it's not, then replace
   that (only that!) ampersand with the `&amp;` string.
3. Continue from where the replaced `&` was and keep iterating until you have covered
   the complete `<loc/>` element.

After that you can run the XML parser and since all the invalid ampersand character codes have been replaced you should be able to get a well-formed XML, that is unless there are other issues with it.

Note that this is just out of the top of my head.